# sorting a list on based on identical values in the list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, sorting

(Using Python 3)

I want to sort a list of lists by the values and the string in the smaller list and print them like so:

(This is just a simplified example of what I'm trying to do)

`a 4
a 3
b 3
c 3
a 2
b 2
c 2
d 2
a 1
b 1
c 1
d 1`

In my code i used

`my_list = sorted(mylist, key=itemgetter(1), reverse=True)`

and obtained something like

`[['a', 4], ['c', 3], ['b', 3], ['a', 3], ['d', 2], ['c', 2], ['b', 2], ['a', 2], ['d', 1], ['c', 1], ['b', 1], ['a', 1]]`

As you can see my values are decreasing like I want them. However, the strings in the smaller lists that have the same value are in anti-alphabetical order.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python uses a stable sort so for ties, items will show up in the same order they occurred. You can sort on multiple keys, but that will reverse the sort for both:

```
my_list = sorted(mylist, key=itemgetter(1, 0), reverse=True)
```

or sort twice since you only want one of the sorts reversed:

```
my_list = sorted(sorted(my_list, key=itemgetter(0)), key=itemgetter(1), reverse=True)
```

Comment: oh i didn't see you don't want letters reversed, you can double sort for that